# Как обратиться к полю поля JSON в React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Имею полученньій из API JSON-запрос ежедневньіх курсов валют за месяц.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "timeseries": true,
    "start_date": "2022-09-01",
    "end_date": "2022-10-01",
    "base": "UAH",
    "rates": {
        "2022-09-01": {
            "AED": 0.099423,
            "AFN": 2.381977,
            "ALL": 3.198081,
            "AMD": 10.95549,
            "ANG": 0.048801,
            "AOA": 11.600827,
            "ARS": 3.766735,
            ...
```

Пьітаюсь из запроса вьітащить перечень всех валют например из одного дня, чтобьі поместить в вьіпадающий список. Наличие самих дней в файле сильно мешает, без них бьі уже реализовал. Кусок кода, в котором пьітаюсь єто сделать:

```
function App() {
    const [currencyOptions, setCurrencyOptions] = useState([])
    console.log(currencyOptions)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("ttps://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/timeseries?start_date=2022-09-01&end_date=2022-10-01&base=UAH", requestOptions)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setCurrencyOptions([data.base, ...Object.keys(data.rates)]) <---- Вот он
            })
    }, [])
```

js-файл, в котором пьітаюсь засунуть полученньіе результатьі в список:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CurrencyRow(props) {
    const {
        currencyOptions
    } = props
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="number" />
            <select>
                {currencyOptions.map(option => (
                    <option value={option}>{option}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Результат в консоли:

[image: Результат в консоли]

Результат на сайте:
[image: Результат на сайте]

Подскажите как обратиться нормально к полю, чтобьі я в options получал нужньіе данньіе (кодировки валют).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример, как работать с такими данными.

```
// Тут эмулируем данные которые должны прийти
const incomeData = {
  "rates": {
    "2022-09-01": {
      "AED": 0.099423,
      "AFN": 2.381977,
      "ALL": 3.198081,
      "AMD": 10.95549,
      "ANG": 0.048801,
      "AOA": 11.600827,
      "ARS": 3.766735,
    },
    "2022-09-02": {
      "AED": 1.099423,
      "AFN": 2.381977,
      "ALL": 3.198081,
      "AMD": 10.95549,
      "ANG": 0.048801,
      "AOA": 11.600827,
      "ARS": 3.766735,
    },
    "2022-09-03": {
      "AED": 3.099423,
      "AFN": 2.381977,
      "ALL": 3.198081,
      "AMD": 10.95549,
      "ANG": 0.048801,
      "AOA": 11.600827,
      "ARS": 3.766735,
    },
  }
}

function App() {
  // Здесь храним веcь объект
  const [rates, setRates] = useState({})
  // Даты для выбора
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([])
  // Список для рендера
  const [rateRender, setRateRender] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keys = Object.keys(incomeData.rates)
    setDates([ ...keys])
    setRates(incomeData.rates)
  }, []);
  // Если набор дат изменился, и нет массива для рендера, подставляем первую дату
  useEffect(() => {
    if (dates.length && !rateRender.length) {
      getRates(dates[0])
    }
  }, [dates])
  // Функция преобразования объекта курсов в массив по выбранной дате
  const getRates = (date) => {
    const rateSelect = rates[date];
    const rate = [];
    for (let x in rateSelect) {
      rate.push({
        name: x,
        value: rateSelect[x]
      })
    }
    setRateRender(rate);
  }

  // Рендерим
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
        Дата: <select onChange={(e) => getRates(e.currentTarget.value)}>
        {dates.map((item) => {
          return <option key={item} value={item}>{item}</option>
        })}
      </select>
        Курс:
        {rateRender.length && <select>
          {rateRender.map(item => {
            return <option key={item.name} id={item.name} value={item.value}>{item.name}: {item.value}</option>
          })}
        </select>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Если вы хотите отображать данные только за какую то конкретную дату, то можно сразу преобразовать данные в массив и передать вашему компоненту.
Это просто пример, как можно сделать. Применение данного примера в вашем проекту уже делайте самостоятельно, исходя из ваших потребностей и необходимого поведения